# Go: combining multiple responses into a single response

Tags: go

I have a usecase wherein I need to split an incoming request into multiple requests(need to handle a multi-tenant case), dispatch these individual requests downstream and then combine together the responses(and errors, if any).

I am trying to achieve it with middleware. I already have a stack of middlewares written doing their specific jobs, so I plan to write a new middleware and add it to existing stack of middlewares. In my middleware:

```
func (p splitQuery) HandleRequest(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
   ....extract individual tenants from incoming request
   ....create a new request for each tenant

   errors := ....
   responses := ....
   for idx, request := range requests {
    p.nextHandler.HandleRequest(request)
    resp, err := p.next.RoundTrip(request)
    if err != nil {
        errors[idx] = err
    }
    responses[idx] = resp
   }
   
   ....combine responses and errors?
}
```

I am not sure what is best Go practise to combine multiple responses into a single one.

Comment: What is the strategy you want to combine all responses? Is it just a concatenation? What happens if there is an error, do you want to return a non-200, or just a `nil` `*http.Response`? Can you show an example of an input request and the response you want? Also, do you need parallelism to run your sub requests, or just sequentially run them?